# Removing polygons from sf simple feature collection

Tags: r, sf

I'm working with a shapefile of national parks in Costa Rica, and I'm trying to get rid of the marine reserves and national parks consisting of water.

To download the dataset:

```
#create data driectory
    if (!dir.exists('data')) {
  dir.create('data')
}

#download dataset from ProtectedPlanet
nps_URL <- 'https://www.protectedplanet.net/downloads/WDPA_Feb2020_search_costa_rica_Costa_Rica,National_P_bf6ceea4036fb52f7e08497edb2f615999e7fffcbc1e2335dd6dbb78f3fd06a5?type=shapefile'
nps_filename <- './data/WDPA_Feb2020_search_costa_rica_Costa_Rica,National_P_bf6ceea4036fb52f7e08497edb2f615999e7fffcbc1e2335dd6dbb78f3fd06a5-shapefile-polygons.shp'
if (!file.exists(nps_filename)) {
  download.file(url = nps_URL, destfile = './data/nps.zip', method = 'auto')
  unzip('./data/nps.zip', exdir = './data')
}

#load the national parks as 'natparks'
natparks <- st_read(dsn = nps_filename)
```

Next, I have a vector containing the name strings of the national parks to be removed:

```
marinereserves <- c("Marino Ballena","Cahuita","Manuel Antonio","Tortuguero","Santa Rosa","Isla del Coco","Marino las Baulas de Guanacaste")
```

Then when trying to remove them, I thought of simply subsetting them by:

```
natparks_sub <- natparks[natparks$NAME == marinereserves,,drop=TRUE]
```

However, this removes nearly all national parks. Strangely enough it only keeps 2 parks, both of them are also in the marinereserves vector.

How can I properly remove the mentioned national parks from the simple feature collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test if any of the park `NAME` attributes are *in* the list of reserves:

```
> natparks_sub <- natparks[natparks$NAME %in% marinereserves,,drop=TRUE]
> dim(natparks_sub)
[1]  7 29
```

Using `==` here tests each element of `NAME` with each element of `marinereserves` in turn. You would have got a warning if not for the chance that you have 7 marine reserve names and 28 national parks. EG if I drop the first park so there's only 27...

```
> natparks_sub <- natparks[natparks[-1,]$NAME == marinereserves,,drop=TRUE]
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(natparks[-1, ]$NAME, marinereserves) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This all goes back to R "recycling" shorter vectors when doing vector-vector operations:

```
> (1:12) == (1:3)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> (1:12) == (1:7)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In (1:12) == (1:7) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

but you need to use `%in%` when testing for inclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped and was interesting to learn as well.